# Development of a website all components necessary?

Tags: php, mysql, html, web

Hey guys I'm developing a website and first project with a group of friends and would like to know if we have covered all the basis, please let me know if I have missed anything out.

Website itself, this will be made up of HTML, JavaScript and PHP(communicate with database)
Database, straightforward mysql.

I would like to know if there is anything we should worry about, e.g. any security concerns, I have completed websites and databases previously but never joined them.

There will be no purchases through the website and its mainly for information and communication between employees.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could add a bit CSS ;-) . I think you should develop it, let other people test it and take ther opinions on it. You should provide the user from doing sql injections in your site.

Answer (score 2):

As a novice there is probably some security holes in your php code. Make sure to understand what is an SQL injection and XSS and check if your code is safe before you release it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using a framework (there are several out there for PHP, like Zend or Cake).  The advantage of this is that the framework takes care of some things for you (authentication, for example) and provides a bit of hand holding.

If this is your first large database-backed website, your code is likely to be a mess... a good MVC framework can force you to do things properly (making maintenance easier).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a framework (well, heck, even if you are), please read and understand everything in the [PHP Manual page on SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

I wouldn't be surprised if this question were closed as too broad or not a real question, but couldn't pass up the opportunity to say "understand SQL injections and avoid them."